# Me salta el error: Namerror

Tags: python

Estoy creando una blockchain y me sale el siguiente error en la consola:

```
    if length > max_length and self.is_chain_valid(chain):
NameError: name 'length' is not defined
```

Creo que el error está dentro `replace_chain`. Dejo aquí la parte del código de la blockchain donde falla:

```
class Blockchain:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.chain = []
        self.transactions = []        
        self.create_block(proof = 1, previous_hash = '0')        
        self.nodes = set()

    def add_node(self,address):
        parsed_url = urlparse(address)
        self.nodes.add(parsed_url.netloc)
        
    def replace_chain(self):
        network = self.nodes
        longest_chain = None
        max_length = len(self.chain)
        
        for node in network:
            response = requests.get(f'http://{node}/get_chain')
            if response.status_code == 200:
                self.length = response.json()['length']
                self.chain = response.json()['chain']
                
                if length > max_length and self.is_chain_valid(chain):                   
                    max_length = length
                    longest_chain = chain
                    
            if longest_chain:
                self.chain = longest_chain
                return True
            return False
```

Comment: Nunca le asignastes valor a `length`, que no es lo mismo que `self.length`.

Comment: Mismo problema con `chain`.

Comment: @CandidMoe ¿Entonces que pongo para que sea correcto?

Comment: `self.length` y  `self.chain` son redundantes, pues la información ya está en el json.

Comment: @CandidMoe el length y chain se tienen que actualizar. no entiendo...